# Does $_FILES['userfile']['name'] Return "FileName.ext" or just "FileName"

Tags: php

I'm using this to check and see how long the name of an upload is by saving the name as a string and using `strlen()` to get the length of the name. I need to know if `$_FILES['userfile']['name']` returns the extension as part of the string name so I can strip it off before counting the string length.

Comment: `echo` it and find out

Comment: The extension is part of the filename, why would php strip it?

Comment: PHP doesn't strip it off, but I want to. I just want to know if that's something I'm going to have to include in the program, or if `$_FILES['userfile']['name']` saves me time and returns the name without the extension anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_FILES['file']['name'] returns the actual name of the uploaded file including its extension.

So if you want to get the length of filename's string without extension, please try this:

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $filename);
$length = strlen($withoutExt);
```

Comment: After testing it looks like this works perfectly as long as the extension is either 3 or 4 characters. Is there a way to have this handle shorter or longer extensions?

Comment: there are several ways to do that. please do like this:

$filename = pathinfo('filename.md.txt', PATHINFO_FILENAME); // returns 'filename.md'

Comment: It looks like I mistook the `{3,4}` as a list and not an array. Setting it to `{2,8}` achieved exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: It's my pleasure. ;)